# Using a Dell PowerConnect to set up load balancing/redundancy, 1 switch 2 routres 2 private wan links

Tags: redundancy

We have different locations connected by two different WAN providers. Each site has a dell powerConnect 6224 and two cisco routers with the WAN connections (we don’t have access to router admin). The 6224 connects to each cisco LAN port and to our LAN backbone. We would like the 6224 provide the ip gateway address and load balance and support redundancy, if one of the routes fail. Is this possible?. We can't find any samples on doing this and we have tried with no success. Any help or link to documentation regarding this, will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

MarianoC

Comment: I read this a couple times and can't picture the network layout.. :-/ Maybe make a diagram?

Answer (score 1):

From what it sounds like you want the gateway to be redundant and also provide load balancing.  The Cisco way to do this would be to use [Gateway Load Balancing](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios/12_2t/12_2t15/feature/guide/ft_glbp.html). If you just want the redundancy, HSRP and VRRP can do this.  All of these happen on the router itself.

As far as having redundant connections to the switch from the servers you can do that with various forms of NIC teaming/bonding.

I still don't fully understand all of what you are asking, but maybe the above helps.  One thing I can say for sure though is "not having access to the router admin" is just dysfunctional, and I don't think you are going to have a good solution that doesn't involve the router.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer Kyle.

I'll try to explain me better. In our private network we have have several sites, but let's say we have two. The sites are connected through two different WAN providers and they supply the routers. We want to balance traffic between these two WAN connections, and for that we have placed a dell switch 6224, that should balance the traffic between the two and provide redundancy in case of one of the links failure. 

continued...

Comment: The routers are provided by the WAN companies and we can't manage them. Involve them to exchange routes and configure everything for redundancy is difficult and we like the load balancing and redundancy be done by owerselves. 

I was trying to use GRE at the switch and establish routes based on that, but 6224 doesn't support GRE.

If you have any other idea, I appreciate your comments.

Thanks again,

MarianoC

Comment: Also, one of the WAN links is an MPLS and the other plain IP...